# Invalid template resource property 'Fn::Base64'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am getting the above error  while processing the ec2.json file

This is a valid JSON file, please let me know any issue with the JSON file

```
   "Resources":{  
  "EC2Instance":{  
     "Type":"AWS::EC2::Instance",
     "Properties":{  
        "InstanceType":{  
           "Ref":"InstanceType"
        },
        "SecurityGroups":[  
           {  
              "Ref":"InstanceSecurityGroup"
           }
        ],
        "KeyName":{  
           "Ref":"KeyName"
        },

  "UserData":{  
     "Fn::Base64":{  
        "Fn::Join":[  
           "",
           [  
              "#!/bin/bash \n",
              "sudo apt-get update \n",
              "sudo apt-get install wget python -y \n",
              "echo UD_OF_EC2_1 >> /var/log/user-data.log \n",
              "echo UD_OF_EC2_2 >> /var/log/user-data.log \n",
              "echo UD_OF_EC2_3 >> /var/log/user-data.log \n"
           ]
        ]
     }
  },
```

The minimal reproducible example for scenario I am attaching

please verify this template what is the problem ??
I tried to edit sample template from git hub for adding user data I ma facing the issue

AwsCloudFormer.template

```
  {
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
   "Description":"AWS CloudFormer Beta - template creation prototype application. This tool allows you to create an AWS CloudFormation template from the AWS resources in your AWS account. **Warning** This template creates a single t1.micro instance in your account to run the application - you will be billed for the instance at normal AWS EC2 rates for the t1.micro.",
   "Parameters":{
      "AccessControl":{
         "Description":" The IP address range that can be used to access the CloudFormer tool. NOTE: We highly recommend that you specify a customized address range to lock down the tool.",
         "Type":"String",
         "MinLength":"9",
         "MaxLength":"18",
         "Default":"0.0.0.0/0",
         "AllowedPattern":"(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
         "ConstraintDescription":"must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
      }
   },
   "Mappings":{
      "RegionMap":{
         "us-east-1":{
            "AMI":"ami-21341f48"
         },
         "us-west-2":{
            "AMI":"ami-d6096ee6"
         },
         "us-west-1":{
            "AMI":"ami-ec7c4fa9"
         },
         "eu-west-1":{
            "AMI":"ami-26688051"
         },
         "ap-southeast-1":{
            "AMI":"ami-c0356292"
         },
         "ap-northeast-1":{
            "AMI":"ami-7d1a777c"
         },
         "ap-southeast-2":{
            "AMI":"ami-cd1b84f7"
         },
         "sa-east-1":{
            "AMI":"ami-592d8c44"
         },
         "us-gov-west-1":{
            "AMI":"ami-23c1a500"
         }
      }
   },
   "Resources":{
      "CFNRole":{
         "Type":"AWS::IAM::Role",
         "Properties":{
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument":{
               "Statement":[
                  {
                     "Effect":"Allow",
                     "Principal":{
                        "Service":[
                           "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                        ]
                     },
                     "Action":[
                        "sts:AssumeRole"
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            "Path":"/"
         }
      },
      "UserData":{
         "Fn::Base64":{
            "Fn::Join":[
               ",",
               [
                  "#!/bin/bash -xe",
                  "/bin/touch /tmp/confirm_work.txt"
               ]
            ]
         }
      },
      "CFNRolePolicy":{
         "Type":"AWS::IAM::Policy",
         "Properties":{
            "PolicyName":"CloudFormerPolicy",
            "PolicyDocument":{
               "Statement":[
                  {
                     "Effect":"Allow",
                     "Action":[
                        "autoscaling:Describe*",
                        "cloudfront:List*",
                        "cloudwatch:Describe*",
                        "dynamodb:List*",
                        "dynamodb:Describe*",
                        "ec2:Describe*",
                        "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*",
                        "elasticache:Describe*",
                        "rds:Describe*",
                        "rds:List*",
                        "route53:List*",
                        "s3:List*",
                        "s3:Get*",
                        "s3:PutObject",
                        "sdb:Get*",
                        "sdb:List*",
                        "sns:Get*",
                        "sns:List*",
                        "sqs:Get*",
                        "sqs:List*"
                     ],
                     "Resource":"*"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "Roles":[
               {
                  "Ref":"CFNRole"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "CFNInstanceProfile":{
         "Type":"AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
         "Properties":{
            "Path":"/",
            "Roles":[
               {
                  "Ref":"CFNRole"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "WebServer":{
         "Type":"AWS::EC2::Instance",
         "Properties":{
            "InstanceType":"t1.micro",
            "SecurityGroups":[
               {
                  "Ref":"InstanceSecurityGroup"
               }
            ],
            "ImageId":{
               "Fn::FindInMap":[
                  "RegionMap",
                  {
                     "Ref":"AWS::Region"
                  },
                  "AMI"
               ]
            },
            "IamInstanceProfile":{
               "Ref":"CFNInstanceProfile"
            }
         }
      },
      "InstanceSecurityGroup":{
         "Type":"AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
         "Properties":{
            "GroupDescription":"Enable Access via port 80",
            "SecurityGroupIngress":[
               {
                  "IpProtocol":"tcp",
                  "FromPort":"80",
                  "ToPort":"80",
                  "CidrIp":{
                     "Ref":"AccessControl"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "Outputs":{
      "URL":{
         "Description":"AWS CloudFormer Prototype URL. Use this endpoint to create templates from your account.",
         "Value":{
            "Fn::Join":[
               "",
               [
                  "http://",
                  {
                     "Fn::GetAtt":[
                        "WebServer",
                        "PublicDnsName"
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not look bad, actually. But the JSON you've posted is not valid per se. i guess it's just a snippet. Please create and post a [MCVE], i.e. a minimal complete template for us to try.

Comment: In the code few braces are missing. Did you try this in the UI?

Comment: I have added a minimal reproducible example,

Comment: Fn::Base64 takes a string as input but you are providing a json to it as an input. Try to directly provide the output of Fn::Join as the value.